# "Ban transitive dependencies" causes build to fail even though it apparently worked before

Tags: maven, dependencies, wildfly, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm trying to build [WildFly 10.1.0.Final](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/tree/10.1.0.Final) from source.

The build causes a "ban transitive dependencies" rule to be violated:

```
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanTransitiveDependencies failed with message:
org.wildfly:wildfly-feature-pack:pom:10.1.0.Final
   org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-features-clustering:jar:3.1.6:compile has transitive dependencies:
      xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1.jbossorg-2:compile
         xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1.jbossorg-2:compile
```

This causes the build to fail:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18:46 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-21T22:22:47Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 213M/512M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (ban-transitive-deps) on project wildfly-feature-pack: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
```

I am sure that it must have worked at some point - WildFly is a pretty active open source project and can't imagine a release would have reached Final if it was not even able to build.

I might be missing something (as I have never used Ban Transitive Dependencies before) but I can't understand what has changed between then and now.

First of all, as expected, `wildfly-feature-pack` does depend on `cxf-rt-features-clustering`. Furthermore, we can note that it has a parent of `wildfly-parent`. Finally, the "ban-transitive-deps" rule is specified in this project itself. These things [can all be seen in its POM](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/10.1.0.Final/feature-pack/pom.xml).

The version of `cxf-rt-features-clustering` is [fixed in the parent POM](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/10.1.0.Final/pom.xml#L2249) at the value `${version.org.apache.cxf}` which is [defined in the same POM](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/10.1.0.Final/pom.xml#L121) as "3.1.6".

Looking at [the POM for that artifact](https://barcorpnexus.barcapint.com:8443/nexus/content/repositories/barcorp/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-features-clustering/3.1.6/cxf-rt-features-clustering-3.1.6.pom), it doesn't even depend on `xalan:xalan`. However, it does depend on a whole load of other things. Wouldn't these cause the "ban transitive dependencies" rule to fail? And why does the Maven enforcer plugin "think" that it does depend on `xalan:xalan`?

Furthermore, why does the enforcer output even show that `xalan:xalan` depends on another artifact? Surely it's enough to violate the rule that `wildfly-feature-pack` depends on `cxf-rt-features-clustering` and `cxf-rt-features-clustering` depends on `xalan`? Doesn't that alone mean that `wildfly-feature-pack` has a transitive dependency?

I think I may be misunderstanding the whole "ban transitive dependencies" rule itself. The [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/banTransitiveDependencies.html) is not really very helpful, it just says that this "rule bans all transitive dependencies", which is pretty obvious.

Comment: Did you make any changes to the pom? Upstream is build several times a day and I've not seen this issue.

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins ,no I have not made any changes to POMs. I notice that at least for JBoss EAP (which is based on WildFly) this issue has been observed - see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-5775 - with a workaround being to simply disable the enforcer plugin entirely. This "feels" wrong, as one shouldn't disable quality assurance just because the QA gives you a result you don't like.

Comment: What JDK and version of that JDK are you using?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins `jdk1.8.0_162` on RHEL 7.4, installed as a YUM package

Comment: Are you building from the source zip or the tag from GitHub? I'll see if I can reproduce it locally.

Comment: Tag from GitHub

Comment: I just ran `mvn clean install -DskipTests` on the 10.1.0.Final tag and it worked perfectly for me. I'm not sure what would cause that.

Answer (score 0):

That means that you configured enforcer plugin with that rule that does not allow to have not explicitly defined dependencies.
In this case you have to explicitly add to the POM these section:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1.jbossorg-2</version>
</dependency>
```

UPD: Based on my research Maven version is the reason here. Must be higher then 3.3.1.

Comment: This error is reported on `wildfly-feature-pack`, not `cxf-rt-features-clustering`, which is a third-party dependency. The warning seems to be saying that `xalan` is a dependency of `cxf-rt-features-clustering`, which would seem to violate the rule if true, but it also seems to not be the case as per my question. If it were true, your solution would be the right fix. However it would still beg the question of why did it work before and not now.

Comment: Had to build it  to verify: it seems that you build it in maven earlier than 3.3.1. For Maven 3.1.1 (Windows) I have the same failure. On Maven 3.5.0 (Mac) it goes fine: [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (ban-bad-dependencies) @ wildfly-naming ---
[INFO]

Comment: Check if the following warning is present in your output: [WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message:
To build this project Maven 3.3.1 (or greater) is required. Please install it.

Comment: No, I already know I have to use Maven 3.3.1 or later, I am using the latest Maven 3.5.2 to build this. Also you can see from the build failure in my question that this is due to transitive dependencies not due to Maven version. Can you let me know the exact Maven command you ran? And are you sure you are building 10.1.0.Final, not the snapshot version?

Comment: Sure, I've cloned master from the link above. And then run [mvn clean install] and [mvn --version]

Comment: as per my question I am trying to build `10.1.0.Final`, not master.

Comment: Sorry, i meant no any branches of course. just from your link

Comment: Still, if you clone `master`, it will clone `master`, not the tag. That is just the web UI. you still need to checkout the tag.

Comment: Kidburla, I understand it well. POM has not been changed in libs. Here are my commands if you will: 1. [git clone https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly.git] .  2. [git checkout tags/10.1.0.Final] 3. [mvn clean install]

Comment: after cloning, you need to switch to the wildfly directory before you checkout. other than that, I can't see any issues. not sure why you are not able to reproduce it. I tried it several times, and each time the same error.

Comment: jesus, of course i did cd wildfly. you won't be able to run git without that. sorry, i can't help you more. as i said, i can reproduce it all in older maven version.